# ! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;

Tags: scala, maven, neo4j, noclassdeffounderror

I am running into the above error while using the neo4j-2.3.3 version. Here is the pom file

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <dropwizard.version>0.8.1</dropwizard.version>
    <akka.version>2.3.11</akka.version>
    <aether.version>1.0.2.v20150114</aether.version>
    <neo4j.version>2.3.3</neo4j.version>
    <maven.version>3.3.1</maven.version>
    <cd_phase>deploy</cd_phase>
    <neo4j.ogm.version>2.0.1</neo4j.ogm.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mvn-neo4j</id>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/everything</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-api</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.ogm.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-graphite</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
        <artifactId>blueprints-neo4j2-graph</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-ha</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>neo4j-management</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-testkit_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any reason it doesnt find the class? I checked the effective dependencies and found the following

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

As mentioned in this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/l3HPGme7ND0

Comment: Did you add scala 2.11.7 as a dependency as that google groups question says?

Comment: yes I added it as an explicit dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be scala versioning issue(s): likely one of the classes were incompatible with 2.11.7.  I looked at the `akka` library and it seems ok.

```
 Akka 2.3.11 is released for Scala 2.10.4 and 2.11.5
```

But here is a prime/likely culprit:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>${akka.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The **2.10** is clearly not going to fly with 2.11.X.

Comment: @user_mda OK updated my answer:  take a look you have an incompatible akka version dependency.

Comment: @user_mda  Have you tried my comment above - to remove or update the akka-actor_2.10 dependency?

Comment: I downgraded akka version to 2.3.9 but still get the same

Comment: @user_mda  The akka version was already too old - you want a *newer* one that is compatible with scala 2.11

Comment: @user_mda .  Did you ever get around to removing that old version of akka 2.10 ??